# Extend UIViewController in UITableViewController IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance

i am using a view controller which contain common custom buttons. and i am using this class where i need those buttons . Like create a logout button in this class name logOutViewController and use this class where i need to show the logout button.

```
#import "logOutViewController.h"
@interface TableViewController : logOutViewController
```

This above code shows the logout button on the required viewcontroller.

This code works well in all view controller except UITaleViewController.
because after importing logOutViewController.h if i replace the

```
#import "logOutViewController.h"
@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController
```

UITableViewController to  logOutViewController then the default function in the  UITableViewController class start giving error.

How should i suppose to get the functions of uiviewcontroller class uitableviewcontroller class.

Comment: What's the superclass of logOutViewController?

Comment: UIViewConroller is the super class of logOutViewController

Answer (score 1):

You can work with `UIViewController`, if you say that it works fine with it, just use TableView delegate methods. 
For examle

```
@interface TableViewController : logOutViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

And use all needed methods.
Don't forget to create your `UITableView`

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView
```

And connect it with manually added tableView in IB.

Hope it will help

Comment: thanks for the response.... i implemented the same as there  is no other option to do the same.